# Generate average date for group of dates DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am working to create a summary table for some data on a PO level, where a PO is composed of 5-10 line items which each have individual ship dates. What I'd like to do is create an "Average date" in which the PO shipped, by taking an average of all the dates for each individual line item. For example, in the attached picture the "average date" would be February 25th. [Line item ship dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQ5jv.png). The Code I'm using looks like this (unimportant lines removed), and the `AVERAGE` function seems to be working but returns the value as a number and not a date, and I don't have the option to reformat it as a date.

```
var tbl1 = 
    SUMMARIZE(
        'Packing slip data',
        'Packing slip data'[PO],
        "Average date", AVERAGE('Packing slip data'[Actual Ship Date])
        )
```

Comment: A `measure` would be more flexible, which could be used alongside the *PO* field in a standard table visual. `Average Ship Date = FORMAT( AVERAGE('Packing slip data'[Actual Ship Date]),"dd/mm/yyyy")`

Answer (score 0):

Hello Why do you need to average a date column ? It is not logical. I recommend you to create an Actual Order Date Column, then use a measure like below. Please note that SUMMARIZE() is a perfect function to group by columns, but not creating a new column. Instead you should use a measure like this. I took your code above, and made some changes.

```
VAR Result = 
    ADDCOLUMNS(
       SUMMARIZE(
        'Packing slip data',
        'Packing slip data'[PO]
        ),
        "Average_Shipping_Days", CALCULATE(AVERAGEX('Packing slip data','Packing slip data'[Actual Ship Date] - 'Packing slip data'[Actual Order Date] ))
    )
RETURN Result
```

I hope It helps somehow.

Comment: I needed an average because I'm linking this data source to another one to compare the installation date to the ship date, and the only link I have between the two data sources is PO. So by taking an average it would accurately reflect the date difference between ship date and install date for the entire PO, vs. using one of the several ship dates as the approximate ship date for the entire PO. I ended up keeping the value as a number and using date diff to compare the install date to the numeric avg. ship date and it worked.

Comment: I am pleased that you solved it. 